# Android: Image that should extend out of view bounds is being cropped when rotated

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imageview

I have an ImageView in one of my activities. It contains a square resolution image that has a "center" scaleType property. I have this image rotating with a center anchor point infinitely. however, while rotating, it's being cropped to it's size on creation. I'll try and sketch up some images to show what I mean. See those below.

EDIT: I forgot to add some code, sorry about that.

**XML:**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/SunAndMoon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/sunandmoon"/>
```

**JAVA:**

```
Animation timeofday = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.timeofdayrotation);
timeofday.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
findViewById(R.id.SunAndMoon).startAnimation(timeofday);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/SunAndMoon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sunandmoon"/>
```